# Calling a smart contract with input parameter of type interface

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I have a smart contract with a function that gets an interface (solidity code):

```
contract A {

  function test(MyInterface contractB) public {
    contractB.doSomething();
  }
}

interface MyInterface {

  function doSomething() external;
} 

contract B implements MyInterface  {

  function doSomething() override external {
    //doing something
  }
}
```

Contracts A and B are deployed on the blockchain.
I would like to call `A.test` method preferred using [ethers](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/):

```
const client = new ethers.Contract(contractAaddress, contractAabi, provider)
await client.test()   // how do I send MyInterface here??
```

My question is how do I send contract B as a parameter to method `test`?
I have the address of contract B on the blockchain of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to send the address of B and solidity will get that the address belongs to an instance of that library.

```
const client = new ethers.Contract(contractAaddress, contractAabi, provider)
await client.test(Bdeployment.address)
```

[This question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/96624/error-in-passing-a-contract-or-interface-as-parameter-to-a-function) might help you.

Comment: This did not work for me I get error, Error: invalid type (argument="type", value="INameOfInterfaceFileHere", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)

Comment: You need to create a new question, seems like your problem is in which parameters you are sending

Comment: Yeah you're probably right.

Comment: If you edit the question I can re-upvote it since my situation appears to have been different. Was using ethers v5.